# Выбор двух различных последних результатов

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть такая таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно нужна последняя запись в этой таблице с Id2 = 1 и последняя запись с Id2 = 2.

Проблема в том, что там может быть и 3 и 4. И их нужно будет включить в выборку. Заранее я не знаю сколько Id2 там будет.

У меня на уме вариант с циклом. Возможно проще?

Не могу вот додуматься.

Id - первичный ключ, идентификатор.

MSSQL

Comment: порядок сортировки известен, критерий фильтрации известен, как выбрать только одну запись вроде тоже должно быть известно, как свести, в чем проблема тогда?

Comment: именно так. как вариант, конечно, самый простой. можно пронумеровать оконными функциями и взять с номером 1

Comment: Прошу прощения за неполное описание проблемы, я дополнил.

Comment: тогда то нить вроде `row_number() over (partition by id2 order by id desc)` и взять то, где будут первые номера

Comment: или можно что нить с самоджойном придумать

Comment: `SELECT MAX(id), id2 FROM [table] GROUP BY id2 ORDER BY 1`, не?

Comment: Группировка по id2 и max(id), если я правильно понял.

Comment: бгг, че то я под вечер очевидные вещи из виду упускаю :D